# WPF RowDetailsTemplate SelectedItem and button command

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Firstly, I am using the MVVM design pattern. I have a DataGrid, as shown in the first code snippet below, in which the RowDetailsTemplate is set to another grid, the second code snippet below. The itemsource for the parent grid is an ObservableCollection of type Adult and the itemsource for the sub-grid is an ObservableCollection of type Child, which is a property of the each Adult object. I am trying to set the SelectedItem and button command for each grid so it hits the ViewModel associated with the view and I cannot see where I am going wrong here. Any advice would be great.

```
<DataGrid 
AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
ItemsSource="{Binding AllAdults}" 
SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAdult}" 
RowDetailsTemplate="{DynamicResource RowDetailsTemplate}" 
RowDetailsVisibilityMode="Collapsed">                
<DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ShowAdultInfoCommand, RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}}}" Content="Print"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=AdultId, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Id" IsReadOnly="True" />
</DataGrid.Columns>
```

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="RowDetailsTemplate">
<DataGrid 
    ItemsSource="{Binding AllChildren}" 
    AutoGenerateColumns="False"
    SelectedItem="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}, AncestorLevel=2}, Path=DataContext.SelectedChild}">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Button Command="{Binding Path=DataContext.ShowChildInfoCommand, RelativeSource= {RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type DataGrid}, AncestorLevel=2}}" Content="Show"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        </DataGridTemplateColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=ChildId, Mode=OneWay}" Header="Child Id" IsReadOnly="True" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: download Snoop and check what your DataContext is of your rowdetails, that might help.

Comment: Hi, I got to the bottom of my issue. I just needed to set the indexes on the AncestorLevel correctly and the all works fine. Thanks for the tip. Never heard of Snoop before.